# Integrating ML Kit in Flutter without MLKit Plugin

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I have an app built on flutter, and want to implement ML Kit to the app. I have a pose detection model written in Java and would like to implement this feature to the app. How do I go on about this without using the flutter plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement native code features via method channel but you have to code platform specified seprate code for all platforms.

You can check this link [method channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Another one way is use flutter package [google_ml_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit)